# Markups extension Autodesk.Vault.Markups

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I am attempting to integrate Markups into my forge (APS) application, and I've discovered a helpful extensions:  `Autodesk.Viewing.MarkupsGui`.

However, I'm unsure if it's possible to access its events. My goal is to save all of the markups and text to my database. I have already reviewed the documentation at https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v2/reference/javascript/markupscore/, but it doesn't appear to apply to either of these extensions.

Answer (score 0):

One you finish the edit mode we cannot edit the markups again, it is converted into a SVG output. Also, we need to keep a record of the view state.

```
  // markups we just created as a string
var markupsPersist = markup.generateData()
// current view state (zoom, direction, sections)
var viewerStatePersist = markup.viewer.getState()
// finish edit of markup
markup.leaveEditMode()
// hide markups (and restore Viewer tools)
markup.hide()
```

Next is up to your implementation: submit the markupsPersist and viewerStatePersist  to your server-side and store on your database. Later you can restore with:

```
// restore the view to the state where the markups were created
markup.viewer.restoreState(viewerStatePersist)
// show markups
markup.show();
// show the markups on a layer
markup.loadMarkups(markupsPersist, "layerName")
```